# Android - NPE when using FragmentPagerAdapter and rotating device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, mvp, android-mvp

I am trying to implement an MVP architecture by following [Google's sample todo app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/)

The problem I have is that I am getting a NPE when starting my presenter in the `onResume()` of the fragments. This happens when I change the orientation of the device.

I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with two static fragments.

From what I understand the `FragmentPagerAdapter` is meant to retain the fragments when the screen is rotated which implies the fragments would retain their presenters. However the presenters are null in `onResume()` so there is something I am not understanding.

Here is my current FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                FragmentA fragA = FragmentA.newInstance();
                PresenterA presA = new PresenterA(fragA);
                return fragA;
            case 1:
                FragmentB fragB = FragmentB.newInstance();
                PresenterB presB = new PresenterB(fragB);
                return fragB;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What pattern are you using to instantiate the fragments? When the fragment is recreated the fragment's arguments can be used to restore initial state. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setarguments

Comment: @Luis I've added more details. According to the documentation for FragmentPagerAdapter state should be held in memory so I shouldn't need to explicitly restore state like you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out even with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` the fragment is actually destroyed after configuration changes (eg. screen is rotated), so my initial assumption was wrong. I found this out by overring and adding a print statement in the fragment's `onDestroy` method.

In my case in order to retain the presenter I just had to `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment's `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, fragments in Android are such a hassle, I get frustrated by them to this day after quite a few years of Android development. I use something like this, will be useful in this case:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

            case GlobalAppKeys.FRAGMENT_HOME:
                return HomeFragment.newInstance(pos);
            case GlobalAppKeys.FRAGMENT_NEXT:
                return NextFragment.newInstance(pos);
            default:
                return new Fragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // refresh all fragments when data set changed
        if (object instanceof HomeFragment){
            HomeFragment hF = (HomeFragment) object;
            if (hF != null) {
                hF.updateThisFragment();
            }
        }

        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, getItemPosition() isn't even called when I rotate the screen.